# jQuery SVG print polygon from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Trivial, but I can't seem to print a jQuery SVG polygon from a string or array. Following the example at http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html#polygon works fine.

So I fabricated a string that looks like `[[129.03,192],[151.47,204.8],[134.64,233.6],[112.2,224]]`, but it returns an error: `TypeError: Object [ has no method 'join'`.

The documentation at the previous link hints at `points(number[][2]) being the x/y coordinates, but any combination of variables I stuff in fail.

What's the secret? How can I compile a string or array of points to make a polygon with?

EDIT: polygon example code from link: `svg.polyline([[450,250], 
    [475,250],[475,220],[500,220],[500,250],...], 
    {fill: 'none', stroke: 'blue', strokeWidth: 5});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var arr = [[129.03,192],[151.47,204.8],[134.64,233.6],[112.2,224]]` and it should not be `var arr = "[[129.03,192],[151.47,204.8],[134.64,233.6],[112.2,224]]"` as you have said "So I fabricated a string that looks like "

if you get them as string then do `eval("[[129.03,192],[151.47,204.8],[134.64,233.6],[112.2,224]]")`

But many say eval is evil